# pass data between screens in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

Screens :

```
sealed class Screens(val route: String) {

    object ScreenLoginRoute : Screens(route = "Login")
    object ScreenOtpRoute : Screens(route = "Otp")
}
```

AuthNestedGraph :

```
    fun NavGraphBuilder.authGraph(navController: NavController){

    navigation(startDestination = Screens.ScreenLoginRoute.route, route = Screens.AuthRoute.route){
        composable(route = Screens.ScreenLoginRoute.route) {backStackEntry ->
            LoginScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.ScreenOtpRoute.route) { backStackEntry ->
            OtpScreen(navController = navController, route = backStackEntry)
        }
  }
}
```

Otp Screen :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun OtpScreen(navController: NavController,mobile:String) {

}
```

LoginScreen :

```
navController.navigate(route = Screens.ScreenOtpRoute.route)
```

how to pass mobileNumber from LoginScreen to OtpScreen through AuthNavGraph

Comment: You can use navigation arguments. - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args